# How to linkify an email address using php

Tags: php, mysql, html, regex, email

I found out how to linkify a URL in php [here](http://www.liamdelahunty.com/tips/php_convert_url_to_link.php), but does anyone know how to do this same concept with an email address? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using preg_replace would be ideal.

gar_onn's answer wouldnt work, because if i wrote a sentance like: "I use asterisk@home. It's pretty neat", the whole string would be linkified.

Something like this would be more ideal :

```
$pattern = '/([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9._]*[a-z0-9]*\@[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9_]+[a-z0-9]*\.[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9_-][a-z0-9]+)/i';

$str = preg_replace ($pattern, '<a href="mailto:\\1">\\1</a>', $str);
```

Comment: This regex has some problems with it. For instance, it does not highlight any addresses with a two-letter TLD (basically any country-TLD, such as .us, .no, .se, .it, .es, etc.). It also doesn't allow many of the characters that are allowed in the user part of email addresses, such as a "+" (try dvyjones+important@dvyjones.com). In short, you shouldn't use regexes for email addresses. However, I have to admit I can't think of any other solution here.

Comment: That was just a rough guess, there's for sure some work to be done on it. Definitely not RFC822 grammar. Additionally it wouldn't handle UTF8 or accented characters either! If you were using Perl, [Mail::RFC822::Address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) would do the trick.. Check out that regex!

Answer (score 0):

**ereg_replace function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.** , you should use preg_replace

this will work:
for the e-mails links

```
 $str = preg_replace('#(.*)\@(.*)\.(.*)#','<a href="mailto:\\1@\\2.\\3">Send email</a>',$str);  // replace a mailto (send mail)
```

this will for url's without erg_replace:

```
     $str = preg_replace('=([^\s]*)(www.)([^\s]*)=','<a href="http://\\2\\3" target=\'_new\'>\\2\\3</a>',$str); // better version to shange URL's in links
```

Comment: Thanks for your input and advise. MichaelP is right though, it was changing the whole string into an email link.